# Find the name of a connection based on shape node index in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, nodes, shapes

Is there any way to get the name of a connector based on the node index of a shape in Excel using VBA?  Something like:

```
Dim shp as Shape
Dim i as Integer

For each shp in activesheet.shapes   'loop through all shapes on the active sheet
    If shp.connector = False Then   'if shape is not a connector type
        For i = 1 to shp.ConnectionSiteCount   'loop through all shape nodes
            shp.nodes(i).connector.name   'return the connector name at that node
        Next i
    End If
Next shp
```

I know you can loop through all of the connector shapes to find the begin and end shape, but I want to use the shape and loop through the nodes to see if there is a connector, and if there is, return the name of that connector.